# The resource object with key 'X' was not found

Tags: asp.net, iis

I know there is posts with this issue, but nothing has worked so far.

So my issue is that when I get here:

```
<%$ resources:af.roi.web, InProgressTitle %>
```

The key is not found in the `AppGlobalResources->af.roi.web.resx` file, but I can find the file (and the key) in the folder `bin/App_GlobalResources`.

I have tried changing the Build Action of the resource file, same error.
I have activated `windows feature (compatibility with IIS 6, Classic ASP, ...)`, nothing new.

I know this code work on the `server` with `IIS 6`, but I can't figure how to make it run on my `local` Windows 10 with `IIS 10`.

I hope one of you has an idea. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the solution below:

1. Right click on your resource (resx) file
2. Go to Properties
3. Change "Build Action" to "Content"

If the solution above doesn't work, try "Embedded Resource" option for "Build Action" parameter.

If you are still getting the same error, try changing "Copy to Output Directory" value to "Copy Always". A folder named "App_GlobalResources" will be created when you publish the code. Make sure this folder is in the same location as the page that is giving resource file connection error.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I did try this but nothing has changed. But while tweeking with the options I found that if I "Run Custom Tool" on my resx file the cs code generated is empty, and I dont undertand why. (I use GlobalResourceProxyGenerator as parameter).

Comment: Open the iis, Explore your webiste, check whether there is a resx file under the App_GlobalResources folder, if you do not find the resource files under App_GlobalResources folder then copy.